# Error handling in Express JS after response

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, express

I have been trying different error handling techniques with Express. First I was just using `process.on('uncaughtException')`. I quickly learned that it was bad practice. After that, I tried using the new "Domain" feature in node js. I wrapped each request in a domain, however, if I would send a response and then do some more work on the server (dealing with the same request) it would not catch the errors from those functions after the response was sent. I then tried moving to the built-in error handling with Express using `next(err)`. However, I am running into the same situation. If I send a response and then a function has an error after the response has been sent, my error handler is not called. Here is some code as an example.

```
async.waterfall([
        function(after)
        {
            hashPassword(password, after);
        },
        function(hash, after)
        {
            makeToken(hash, after);
        },
        function(hash, token, after)
        {
            insertUserInfo(email, username, hash, ip, token, after);
        },
        function(token, id, after)
        {
            req.session.attempts = 0;
            res.json({ err: 0, attempts: 0 }); //Response is sent
            after(null, token, id);
        },
        function(token, id, after)
        {
            sendEmail(token, email, renderEmail); //Errors not caught
            makeFolder(id, after); //Errors not caught
        }
    ], function(err) {

        if(err)
            next(err);

    }
);
```

As you can see from the code, I am registering a new user. Now, I could wait until I have completed all of my logic to send back the response but I thought that it would make the request appear much faster for the user if I did some of the less important things after the response has been sent. I am willing to change my code to perform everything THEN send the response, but I want to make sure that there is no solution out there that I have not tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

As awesome as Express JS is, it doesn't have a time travel feature allowing you to unsend a request :) This is really the root of your problem. If your response must display the outcome, then it must wait until all the relevant actions to complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that I am trying to cut corners by sending the response prematurely. However, when I send the response, I have already accomplished everything that the user could have input on, so there are no more errors to display to them. I was just interested in capturing those errors for my log so I can detect any problems if they occur. I can see how this seems like I am asking a lot of Express, but I was just curious as to see if a solution exists.

Comment: I see. If I understand correctly, couldn't you call next() to signal Express that you're done, and that's the end of that as far as the user is concerned. But, that doesn't mean you can't listen for error events that fire long after Express has sent the request. Instead of calling done(err), those event listeners could do logging, etc., or even email the user. Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: That is true. I could set up another error handling system that deals with errors after the response but I wouldn't have the request object anymore to gather details about the user when I log my error and I wouldn't be able to use `next()`. I guess there just isn't anyway to do what I am wanting to do after the response has been sent.

Comment: I think the request object and the user object would still be reachable from your handler via closure, so even though the request stream would be in a closed state, its attendant info (e.g. request headers) won't have been garbage-collected yet.